# How to save MultyPlygon in Django model field

Tags: django, geodjango, shapely

I'm trying to save MultyPlygon to Dajngo MultiPolygonField but get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set Plot SpatialProxy (MULTIPOLYGON) with value of type: <class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon'>

My actual code is

model.py:

```
...
poligon = gis_models.MultiPolygonField(verbose_name=_('Polygon'), blank=True, null=True)
...
```

gml_parser.py:

```
self.plot.poligon = geometry_plot
self.plot.save()
```

The geometry_plot object type is <class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon'>

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your full model which includes the Polygon field. Also edit the question to show a bit more of `gml_parser.py` so I can see what `self` relates to.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

self.plot.poligon = GEOSGeometry(str(geometry_plot))
self.plot.save()
```